# fullcalendar 1.5 background color

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using a modified version of fullcalendar 1.5 (therefore this older version) and I am wondering if we can change the background of a day column in weekly view to be grey from start of day until current time?

Comment: Can you target the IDs/Classes of the control directly with css?

Comment: then I would have to loop trough the cells of the past and modify their attributes with javascript? I also do not know how to get only the cells of the past.

Comment: @jt123: Take a look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `TD Classes`.

```
.fc-today, .fc-future {
 background: grey;
}
```

Comment: ok so I can make a whole day grey with .fc-today but .fc-future does not exist and what I need is something like .fc-past so I would somehow need to add that class name to the cells of the past. also, one cell seem to be wide over every day in the agendaWeek view.